# i want to change behaviour even when an option is not changed in dropdown jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement to include a user input along with dropdown.
I implemented it using .change() method of jquery.
Using .change() function allows me to take the input when i select "Enter value" option.
In order for this code to work again i will have to change the selection. i.e .

When i click on "Enter value" option again, no index will be changed and nothing will happen.
How do i get the focus to the textbox with out changing the selected option. 
In short i want the current functionality to work multiple times with out having to select other options.

My code in js fiddle is :
[My code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTumv/1)

```
jQuery(".gfield_select").change(function() {
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    var enter = jQuery(this).parent().find('option:selected').text();
    var x = jQuery(this).parent();
    if (enter ==="Enter a value" || enter === "Enter value"){
      var holder = x.find('.holder');
      holder.val('');          
      holder.prop('disabled',false);
      holder.focus();
    } else {
      x.find('.holder').val(x.find('option:selected').text());
      x.find('.holder').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the select value to be "0" and thus show "None" after giving focus to the input field.

```
jQuery(".gfield_select").change(function() {
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    var enter = jQuery(this).parent().find('option:selected').text();
    var x = jQuery(this).parent();
    if (enter ==="Enter a value" || enter === "Enter value"){
      var holder = x.find('.holder');
      holder.val('');          
      holder.prop('disabled',false);
      holder.focus();
      jQuery(this).val("0"); // Change select value to None.
    } else {
      x.find('.holder').val(x.find('option:selected').text());
      x.find('.holder').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brange , but that will not solve my query. My code is working as you can check in jsfiddle. I have 3 options. Any options i select will be reflected on the text box. if i select enter value option ,the textbox will be blank and allows me to enter value. However if i again select the Enter value option nothing will happen as no index is changed.

Comment: And that would be fixed with the code I showed you. Test here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLc69/).